# Flutter Android color overlay around screen when using keyboard or controller

Tags: android, flutter, overlay

1. Create new Flutter project in Android Studio
2. Run it
3. If you running the project on android emulator - press any key on PC keyboard (for example Down key or B). If you running the project on mobile device - connect any controller and press any key or arrow. For TV you can use dpad.

Color overlay occurs around the screen.

How can I remove it?

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.6, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-x64, locale en-EE)
    • Flutter version 3.7.6 on channel stable at /Users/huynq/Documents/GitHub/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 12cb4eb7a0 (4 days ago), 2023-03-01 10:29:26 -0800
    • Engine revision ada363ee93
    • Dart version 2.19.3
    • DevTools version 2.20.1
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5dYD.jpg)
[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BblVZ.gif)

I tried to use other themes for the activity, but for some themes I got a full screen overlaying.

Comment: why do you need it? i think it should be happen only emulator.

Comment: @aligur This spoils the user interface when working with the controller. This happens on any device.

Comment: can you try it on release apk?

Comment: @aligur Yes I tried, it no matter which build type I use, the problem is reproduced for all build types.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out it is old issue from 2018 year https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16810.

A partial solution is to add this to the activity/app theme:

```
<item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled">false</item>
```

But it works only for API level 26 and above.